# Checking only "Automatic" services with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services, reboot

I've seen lots of scripts out there for manually stopping/starting services in a list, but how can I generate that list programatically of -just- the automatic services. I want to script some reboots, and am looking for a way to verify that everything did in fact start up correctly for any services that were supposed to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Get-Service` returns `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` objects that do not expose this information. Thus, you should use WMI for this kind of task: `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service`. Example that shows the required `StartMode` and formats the output a la Windows control panel:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
Format-Table -AutoSize @(
    'Name'
    'DisplayName'
    @{ Expression = 'State'; Width = 9 }
    @{ Expression = 'StartMode'; Width = 9 }
    'StartName'
)
```

You are interested in services that are automatic but not running:

```
# get Auto that not Running:
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' } |
# process them; in this example we just show them:
Format-Table -AutoSize @(
    'Name'
    'DisplayName'
    @{ Expression = 'State'; Width = 9 }
    @{ Expression = 'StartMode'; Width = 9 }
    'StartName'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's been bothering me for the longest time and just couldn't quite figure it out.